# add edit table, how to change a row to edit mode?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Below is my razor code for my table of users and the current add/edit layout

```
<table class="smalltable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tblUsers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Dept</th>
            <th>Assyst Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@{ Html.BeginForm("AddEditUser", "Home"); }
                 <input type="submit" value="Add" id="btnSave" name="cmd" class="plain-button" />
            </td>
            <td>@Html.Editor("Forename")</td>
            <td>@Html.Editor("Surname")</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("lstDepts")</td>
            <td>@Html.Editor("AssystName")
             @{ Html.EndForm(); }</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var User in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "AddEditUser", new { id = User.ID }, new { name = "cmd", value = "Edit" })</td>
                <td>
                    @User.Forename
                </td>
                <td>
                    @User.Surname
                </td>
                <td>
                    @User.Dept
                </td>
                <td>
                    @User.AssystName
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What i want to achieve is when a edit is pressed, the row that the edit link was on turns into edit boxes, i how to load up the add form with the edit users details (i could use hidden id and set it with querystring) but i wanted to edit in place really

anyone know how to do this or can point me in the right place?

THanks

Comment: looks too expensive for my requirements

Comment: @AlexW, you can render a text box inside each cell. Set `readonly="readonly"` on them. On click, you just remove this attribute and edit the data. As a side note, consider switching from `foreach` to `for` if you're going to post the data to the server.